# Server side problems saving a file uploaded using requests.POST

Tags: django, python-requests

Below is my python snippet code to upload a file on certain server:

```
import requests
url = "http://<my_url>"
files = {'file':open("<file to be uploaded>", "rb"), "name":"<name of the file>"}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Status code is 200, so it's OK.
My question is, on the server side, how do I save this file?
I can access 'name' on the dict thru this:

```
request.POST.get('name')
```

I can access the 'file' as well but I can't save it. I am trying this:

```
ufile = request.POST.get('file')
dest = open("<file on the server side>", "wb+")
for chunk in ufile.chunks():
   dest.write(chunk)
dest.close()
```

But this is not working and it throws this exception:

```
unicode object has no attribute 'chunks'
```

I also tried:

```
ufile.save(<"filepath on the server side">)
```

But I encountered the same exception.

Hoping for any feedback! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following instead of writing chunk by chunk:

```
dest.write(ufile)
```

The ufile object is a string, not a file handle.

Comment: Thanks Regis. It works! Though I need to include the .read() already on the 'file' of the files dictionary. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Files are not in `request.POST`, they are in `request.FILES`.

But you probably want to read [the file uploads documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/http/file-uploads/).

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I know that they are in request.FILES but I think this is only working if you are uploading via forms... which I am not. I am just uploading it via some method (like a web service method)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue..
You should delete "Content-type" from request header, and your file will appear in `request.FILES`, then you can work with `<TemporaryUploadedFile>`

I think this answer not relevant for @jaysonpryde, but maybe will help someone else.. :)